# Java - Diagonal Movement

Tags: java, path-finding

I'm making a version of SpaceInvaders and I would like my Shoots to have a diagonal movement. I tried to google it, but I can figure out how to do it.

I've got the class Entity:

```
public abstract class Entity extends Parent{
    protected double x;
    protected double y;
    protected double dx;
    protected double dy;
    private Rectangle me = new Rectangle();
    private Rectangle him = new Rectangle();

        Image ref;
        StackPane root;


        ImageView content;
    public Entity(Image ref,int x,int y, StackPane root)  {
                this.ref=ref;
                this.root=root;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;


                content = new ImageView();
                content.setSmooth(true);
                content.setImage(ref);

                content.setScaleX(Game.scalar); 
                content.setScaleY(Game.scalar); 


                content.setTranslateX(this.x);
                content.setTranslateY(this.y);
                content.setRotate(0);

                Game.root.getChildren().add(content);



    }

    public void move(long delta) {
        this.x += (delta * this.dx) / 1000;
        this.y += (delta * this.dy) / 1000;

         content.setTranslateX(this.x);
         content.setTranslateY(this.y);


    }
```

Now, how could I set a diagonal movement? I printed the game with the **Shoot Entity**.

Thaks.
[image: Alien Shoot]

Comment: A few things: you'll have to rotate your image to show which angle your shot is traveling at. After that, your X will have to be altered to travel along the diagonal path.

Comment: @Frecklefoot I can rotate the image...that won't be a problem...but I don't know how to create that diagonal path

Comment: Well, that's really geometry, but if you want it to move at a simple 45° angle, that's pretty straight-forward. If we assume that `y` always decreases for each movement delta, then we just change the `x` position for each Shoot Entity each time you update its position. If it is moving diagonally to the left, `x = x - 1`. If it is moving diagonally to the right `x = x + 1`. You can substitute whatever number is appropriate in your case instead of `1`.

Comment: @Frecklefoot I managed to make x = x + 1. Now I've got another problem : When I set rotate to 30° angle, how should I set the x :) to get the diagonal by the rotated image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use trigonometry, in particular `sin` and `cos`. The standard java class `Math` has those methods.

For example, we could think that a bullet traveling from the bottom to the top is going at an angle of 90 degrees (0 is from left to right, 180 is from right to left and 270 is from top to bottom):

```
double angle = 90.0;
double angleInRadians = Math.toRadians(angle);  // convert from degrees to radians
x += Math.cos(angleInRadians);  // cos of 90 is 0, so no horizontal movement
y += Math.sin(angleInRadians);  // sin of 90 is 1, full vertical movement
```

To go diagonal just use a different angle, for example with 60 degree the bullet will travel both horizontally and vertically:

```
double angle = 60.0;
double angleInRadians = Math.toRadians(angle);  // convert from degrees to radians
x += Math.cos(angleInRadians);  // cos of 60 is 0.58.., so a bit of horizontal movement
y += Math.sin(angleInRadians);  // sin of 60 is 0.80.., a decent amount of vertical movement
```

#### Why sine and cosine? A visual representation.

The image below show what we want to achieve, basically find the `delta x` and `delta y` to add to our `origin` position in order to reach the `destination` position, which are not perpendicular to each other.

[image: The situation representation]

Now let's take a look at what `sine` and `cosine` represent:

[image: sine and cosine representation]

(Source: Wikipedia.)

We can notice the similarities: the points `O` and `P` are respectively our `origin` and `destination`, while `sin θ` and `cos θ` corresponds to `delta y` and `delta x`.

Applying these concepts to our situation we end up with:

[image: sine and cosine applied]

Sine and cosine require an angle, which will define the movement direction of our object.

They will return a value between -1 and 1, so we will need to multiply it with a coefficient if we want to change the object movement "speed".

Comment: Thanks. It works great.

Comment: @Lois Securo What should I do to get more digonal then <0,1> ?

Comment: just multiply with a coefficient, for example `Math.cos(angleInRadians) * speed`

Answer (score 0):

Based on limited information you've provided, I'm assuming `x` and `y` are the coordinates of your spaceship, while `dx` and `dy` are coordinates of the projectile's target. You can use `Math.atan2()` to calculate rotation degree for a projectile image and supply it to `content.setRotate()` you have there.

```
// consider your spaceship an origin in coordinate system
double relativeX = this.dx - this.x;
double relativeY = this.y - this.dy;

double degree = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(relativeY, relativeX));

// rotate a projectile image counterclockwise from horizontal direction
content.setRotate(90 - degree);
```